# Complex Django Query Spanning Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

Table set up for reference only:

```
class CustomerInformation(Model):
    first_name = charfield()
    last_name = charfield()

class CustomerCreditInformation(Model):
    customer = OneToOneField(CustomerInformation, on_delete=CASCADE)
    max_credit_amount = DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Credit Amount')
    due_in = CharField(choices=PAYMENT_DUE_DATES,
                       max_length=4, verbose_name='Payable before')

Class Invoice(Model):
    financial_party = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomerInformation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="Submit Invoice To:")
    date_billed_original = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Billed Date', editable=False, null=True)

class InvoicePayment(models.Model, ListViewModelFunctions):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Payment Amount')

class Charges(models.Model, ListViewModelFunctions):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
```

Invoices could be created, but not billed, meaning charges may be created on invoices that have not been billed.

Given the following table set up, is there a way to create a "single" query from the Customer table that accomplishes the following (listed in order of difficulty):

1. Concat First/Last Name (simple concat here works no issues/already completed)
2. Annotate the Customers Credit Max Amount (Simple annotate here works/already completed)
3. Annotate outstanding charges for all billed invoices (the filter is what throws me off)
4. Annotate The total outstanding based on the date billed being less than timezone.localdate() - timedelta(customercredit__due_in).

The resulting query would return a data dict with: Name, Customer Credit Amount, Total Outstanding Invoices (billed to date), Total Outstanding Invoices from past due invoices only.

I have successfully accomplished this from the Invoice Model, but my client has a need to see this from the customer Table, as there is more functionality on the customer listing pages in addition to the information on the customers model that isn't listed in the models.

I have Manager Functions written for the Invoice Model that handles most of this information such as: AnnotatePayments (which takes the sum of all charges for an invoice, and sum of all payments for an invoice showing the outstanding balance in an annotated field) and BilledNotPaid invoices(calls annotatePayments excluding jobs not billed yet).

From my searching I cannot find a way to utilize these manager functions through a subquery or similar in Django, and would prefer not to "duplicate" the logic of these manager functions to accomplish this one template/page.

Comment: Instead of `Manager` methods, it sounds like you may `QuerySet` methods instead. [The Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods) don't give an obvious example of this, but custom methods defined on a subclass of `QuerySet` will be chainable.

Comment: @Supra621 that is what I mean by Manager, all of the Managers are set up by extending the queryset.   The issue, this manager lives on the Invoice Table not the Customer Table which I would need to invoke. 

If It is possible to access those queryset functions on the Invoice Table from the Customer Table, that would be the gold I need to get this done.

Comment: In that case, my next thought as to what you might be looking for would be [custom reverse managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#using-a-custom-reverse-manager). That would let you traverse from one model to the objects of another, with the custom methods available for whichever manager you specify.

Comment: At the time of making the query, I don't have an object to access the related manager from, I am still in the customer manager (queryset)

Comment: I see - maybe post your `Manager` and/or `QuerySet` class code, and a query you've tried so far?

Comment: At this point I broke it up to get what I needed.  More hits to the db, but needed to get a solution.